# How do I use sqlalchemy to order results by a list?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have an `Inventory` table, with a `status` column with the following possible values: voided, to_order, priority, received and ordered.

When I query the database I would like to order the status column in this order:

```
to_order, priority, received, ordered, voided.
```

**How do I use sqlalchemy to order my results by a list order?**

My starting point is this: `sort = desc(Inventory.status)`, and I'm unaware as to define my own sort order.

Comment: If this ordering is reused, then one option would be to create (or extend) the `InventoryStatus` table, which will contain columns such as `name` and `sort_order`. Then your queries could join to this table and order results by the column from joined table. I often have other qualifier/flag columns, which are used for other purposes. For example, one could have flag `completed` (which would be True for `received` and `voided`) to indicate that no User action is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to resort to the `ORDER BY` + `CASE` combination.

Talking about pure SQL first, have a look at [this example](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-custom-sort-in-sql-order-by-clause).

```
ORDER BY (
    CASE currency_code

    WHEN 'USD'
    THEN 1

    WHEN 'EUR'
    THEN 2

    ...

    END
) ASC
```

Fortunately, it's possible to do exactly this in SQLAlchemy's ORM, combining `order_by` and [case](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case).